# node JS GET request not reflects changes in frontend from database of mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, post, get

I've my setup as given below.
Database - MongoDB
Front end - React JS App
middleware - Node API
As I add some entries in database, & retrieve them back using the `GET` request. I didn't get new entries, whereas I change the method from `GET` to `POST` API is able to show the changes in data retrieved using the same API.
Where I stuck is why `GET` couldn't retrieve the changes in database as `POST` can do

Comment: Please add a code example, hard to diagnose the problem without it

Comment: Actually it's 3 sided code. Like Front-end, Middleware & Backend. In such case what should I provide in code.

Comment: Provide snippets of all 3

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. But I get it working. with POST method. And thanks dude for your instant replies.

Comment: No problem buddy